# access input type text value from inside a tr td using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am new to web development and I keep getting caught up in errors while trying to iterate table row data values .... I have searched and read many places.

First I wanted to access `table tr td text`

I've done that using JavaScript code from someones articles, it worked fine since I wanted to access td input type text values... I was not able to do that

```js
var myTab = document.getElementById('invoiceTable');
for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {


  var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;

  for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {
    var descriptionInvoice = objCells.item(3).innerHTML;

  }
}
```

```html
<table id="invoiceTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sno</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>discount</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>HANON BALLON</td>
      <td>PIECE </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="" value="1" required=""> </td>
      <td>232</td>
      <td><input class="" type="text" name="discount" value="0"></td>
      <td>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt btnDelete"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have accessed the row but was not able to access input type text value
[image: tr td]

Comment: objCells.item(3) should be the whole Input Field so if you console.log(objCells.item(3)) you can expect <input type="text" name="" id="" value="1" required=""> there if that is the case all you need to do is access its value by using objCells.item(3).value

Answer (score 0):

You can get all *#invoiceTable's* *td's* *input fields* with the *type text* by the selector

```
document.querySelectorAll('#invoiceTable td input[type="text"]')
```

You can then iterate over the elements by using *forEach* and read its value by accessing the *.value* property. *Note: You can also use a old fashioned for-loop if you prefer it*

```
.forEach(x => {
    console.log(x.value);
  }
);
```

```js
// access all <td> input type texts value
document.querySelectorAll('#invoiceTable  td input[type="text"]').forEach(x => {
    console.log(x.value);
  }
);
```

```html
<table id="invoiceTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sno</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>discount</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>HANON BALLON</td>
      <td>PIECE </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="" value="1" required=""> </td>
      <td>232</td>
      <td><input class="" type="text" name="discount" value="0"></td>
      <td>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt btnDelete"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Teemu where does it consider to check if its type is text?

Comment: Who cares, it's the first input in that table. OP didn't give any alternatives to the markup. Also, your code hits both of the inputs. If the type is that important, then add it: `myTab.querySelector('input[type="text"]')`.

Comment: @Teemu yes that's a smarter solution ^^

Comment: @Teemu OP has asked for *I done that using java script code from someones article , it worked fine until i wanted to access td input type text values... i was not able to do that*
He asked for
**values** I thought he want all the values of the input fields type text but yes it is ambigous because in the question title he asked for a value.

Comment: Who knows what OP really wants ... A small tip for selectors: Descendant combinators are slow (when having a large document), they first try to find the element matching the last selector in the list, and then traverse up to the DOM until the element matching the next to left selector has been found. If there's no matching element, the next element matching the last selector is searched, etc. That's why it's good practice to limit the search inside a particular element only, and not search through the entire document.

Comment: @Teemu thanks for the tip, appreciate it. This means I shoudn't search for the td's in the whole document, instead just looking for the td's inside this specifc table?

Comment: Depends on the document, and the size of the table, if there's only a single small table, the difference is negligible. Anyway, the inputs are in `td`s anyway, there's no need to check that, if the selector already matches a table.

Comment: hi thank you for answering ... i am developing an application where i need to calculate total amount by processing all the available input fileds 

quantity
price
discount

so i was finding a way to get the input text field value by using the way mentioned in javascript code

Comment: @MohammadAwais if you think this was helpful, mark it as accepted the button below dowm- upvoting